# How to select all columns from a table but with unique one column

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

I have a table with a lot of columns and I want to select all columns but I want unique one of these columns.

This works for me but I don't get all columns:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT company FROM table t $order");
```

I also tested this but doesn't do anything:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * DISTINCT company FROM table t $order");


$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT company * FROM table t $order");
```

EDIT

My table has a lot of columns let's say it has 5 so an example of my records is this:

```
company   x      y     price   numOfEmpl
one       1      5     1.3     15
one       2      6     1.4     15
two       3      7     1.5     16
three     4      8     1.6     17
```

So I want to cut the second line and take all the others.

Comment: Have you looked at GROUP BY

Comment: @RiggsFolly no actually I don't know how it works with group by

Comment: Then [here is where you need to start your research](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Edited previous answer based on extra information**

Have a solution for you in MySQL and in SQL Server if you need it

**MySQL Example (Using User Variables/Sub-Queries)**

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable (company VARCHAR(20), x INT, y INT, price FLOAT, numOfEmploy INT);

INSERT INTO SomeTable 
(company, x, y, price, numOfEmploy) 
VALUES 
('one', 1, 5, 1.3, 15),
('one', 1, 6, 1.4, 15),
('two', 1, 7, 1.5, 16),
('three', 1, 8, 1.6, 17);

SET @count = NULL, @value = NULL;
SELECT company, x, y, price, numOfEmploy FROM (
    SELECT 
        company, x, y, price, numOfEmploy,
        @count := IF(@value = company, @count + 1, 1) AS rc,
        @value := company
    FROM SomeTable
) AS grouped_companies WHERE rc = 1
```

**SQL Server Example (Using CTE)**

```
--Create the table
declare @sometable table ( company varchar(10), x int, y int, price float, numOfEmploy int)

--insert the data
insert into @sometable values ('one', 1, 5, 1.3, 15)
insert into @sometable values ('one', 2, 6, 1.4, 15)
insert into @sometable values ('two', 3, 7, 1.5, 16)
insert into @sometable values ('three', 4, 8, 1.6, 17)

--WITH Common Table Expression
;WITH grouped_companies AS (
        SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY company
                            ORDER BY company) AS rc
        FROM @sometable)
SELECT gc.company, gc.x, gc.y, gc.price, gc.numOfEmploy
FROM grouped_companies gc
WHERE gc.rc = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what should I put inside sum? (if i want all the other columns)

Comment: In my example, SUM() would add together all of the Order Totals for each company.

Comment: Ok if i want to take all records but cut duplicates what should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you want the data to be presented, but getting a distinct list of companies but providing all the other columns kind of contradicts itself. Could you provide an example in your question of how you want it to look?

Comment: If its to present on the front-end you might be better splitting it into two queries - One getting a list of distinct companies, and another getting all the records for that company. Then have your PHP code loop through each distinct company returned from the first query and call the second

Comment: OK yes I see what you're trying to do. What do you want to happen to the data in row two though? Do you literally only want to display rows 1,3, and 4? Or do you want to somehow combine data from the non-distinct columns (x,y,price,numOfEmpl) into a single row? If its the latter, your query would need to use an aggregate function for each of the non-distinct columns to let it know.

Comment: I want the first you mentioned (I need only rows 1,3,4)

Comment: Just edited my answer with what you will need to get this running. Hopefully that fixes it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `DISTINCT` keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values within defined columns, like

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
```

or you can return the amount of DISTINCT values by

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name)
```

[See some samples on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

I think you might need to use a seperate `sql query` for all the records